# Get the Type category for the URLs using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

For this [URL](http://www.jabong.com/women/clothing/tops-tees-shirts/tops) , I need all the product URLs and their respective TYPE.

So the output should be:

```
Product_URL1 Blouse
Product_URL2 Crop Top
Product_URL3 Tank Top
Product_URL4 Strappy Top
Product_URL5 Tube Top
```

Below is my code, I guess everything is right expect the xpath for the item['type']

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
import scrapy
from scrapy.http.request import Request

class JabongItem(scrapy.Item):
  base_link = scrapy.Field()
  type = scrapy.Field()
  count = scrapy.Field()
  product_name = scrapy.Field()
  product_link = scrapy.Field()


class JabongScrape(CrawlSpider):
    name = "jabong"
    allowed_domains = "jabong.com"
    start_urls = ["http://www.jabong.com/women/clothing/tops-tees-shirts/tops", "http://www.jabong.com/women/clothing/tops-tees-shirts/tees"]


    def parse(self, response):
        item=JabongItem()
        try:
            for idx in range(0, 20):
                item['type']=response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'options')]/label/a/text()").extract()[idx]
                item['base_link']=response.url+response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'options')]/label/a/@href").extract()[idx] + "?ax=1&page=1&limit=" + (response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'options')]/label/small/text()").extract()[idx]).replace("[","").replace("]","") + "&sortField=popularity&sortBy=desc"
                item['count']= (response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'options')]/label/small/text()").extract()[idx]).replace("[","").replace("]","")
                yield Request(item['base_link'],callback=self.parse_product_link,
                      meta={'item': item, 'count': int(item['count'])}, dont_filter=True)
        except:
            pass

    def parse_product_link(self,response):
        item=response.meta['item']
        try:
            for i in range(0, response.meta['count']):
                item['product_link']=response.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'col-xxs-6 col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 product-tile img-responsive')]/a/@href").extract()[i]
                # item['original_price']=response.xpath("section.row > div:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > span:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)::text").extract()[idx]
                print i
                yield item
        except:
            pass
```

And the jbng_base_links.txt contains "http://www.jabong.com/women/clothing/tops-tees-shirts/tops"

Comment: My suggestion would be to scrape with `Spider` instead of `CrawlSpider` and scrape each type separately, they have different links for example blouses http://www.jabong.com/women/clothing/tops-tees-shirts/tops/blouses/

Answer (score 1):

As Rafael pointed out the easiest way of doing this is simply restructuring your spider manually to follow this order:

1. Go to webpage
2. Find type urls
3. Go to every type url -> scrape items

It could be as simple as:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'myspider'
    start_urls = []

    def parse(self, response):
        """this will parse landing page for type urls"""
        urls = response.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Type')]/..//a/@href").extract()
        for url in urls:
            url = response.urljoin(url)
            yield scrapy.Requests(url, self.parse_type)

    def parse_type(self, response):
        """this will parse every type page for items"""
        type_name = response.xpath("//a[@class='filtered-brand']/text()").extract_first()  
        product_urls = ...
        for url in product_urls:
            yield {'type': type_name, 'url': url}
        # handle next page
```